# Find all where parameter is within an array - Waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

In pseudo code, it'd be as so

> Find all businesses where the outcodes array contains NG1

I'm having a hard time finding something that works, and waterline throws it's Invalid usage at everything I try.

```
  Business.find({
    or:{outcodes: {contains: 'NG1 4RQ' }}
  })
```

For reference, my business model contains outcodes as an array:

```
  outcodes:       { type: 'array' },
```

Is anyone able to advise how I can achieve this.  I'm stumped.  Currently using SailsJS with Waterline ORM

Answer (score 0):

The or is not working because it needs to be an array. With only 1 criteria, you don't need to use or, but here's an example using or and searching an array for a partial string.

```
Business.find({
  or: [ { outcodes: { contains: 'NG1' }}]
}).exec(function(err, businesses){...});
```